# Why Scrapy hash url when downloading image?

Tags: web-scraping, scrapy

Why Scrapy hash url when downloading image, as seen here https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/media-pipeline.html, where SHA1 is used to hash the url to give the name for each image? Is there any practical advantage of doing this?

Comment: Could you elaborate more? Where do you see this hashing?

Comment: @Granitosaurus I have edited the post to give more information. You obviously don't use Scrapy enough to be eligible to answer this post.

Answer (score 4):

I don't think there are any major advantages to storing files as sha1 hashed urls.
There are few minor advantages though:

- Getting rid of unsafe characters - characters such as `/:.` are not always system safe, having filename just be some word characters + `.jpg` is very convenient.
- Contstant length (might be useful in some rare cases).
- Easy to validate for dupe filterting and such as the same url will has out to same filename.

Personally I think it's a pretty lazy solution. Fortunately it can be extended, though it's not as straight-forward as it should be.

```
class MyImagesPipeline(ImagesPipeline):
    def filename(url):
        return url.replace(string.letters + '-_.', '')

    def file_path(self, request, response=None, info=None):
        # the original code
        # image_guid = hashlib.sha1(to_bytes(url)).hexdigest()
        # return 'full/%s.jpg' % (image_guid)
        # our code
        return 'full/' + self.filename(response.url)

    def thumb_path(self, request, response=None, info=None):
        return 'thumb/' + self.filename(response.url)
```

And enable it in your `settings.py`